# Significance of Bing's enboldening of some search results

Tags: bing

What's the significance of Bing's enboldening in some search result entries?

I have found no answer to this from web search using Google... or Bing :)

For example, some words in some entries (inc. different words in identical phrases):

http://www.bing.com/search?q=London&q1=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.chrisjj.com%2Ftango%2Fcjjsets%2F

->

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug due to bungled highlighting of term matches.

A simpler case:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=Carablanca+falta+Chris

->

Bad highlighting on results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xltFy.png (bold)

Bad highlighting on cached page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WByOR.png (red)